# Tooltip overwritten for moving images in D3

Tags: d3.js, svg, tooltip

Here i'm working on moving images dynamically with random x and y, inside a zooming & dragging SVG. And also added tooltip for these images inside the loop itself. When the tooltip appears its content is overwritten with last element's tooltip. Please check out the [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/NayanaDas/h4y06kvn/). In the following code, inside the for loop, I try to display the tooltip as "user tooltip:"+i, but the last tooltip content is displayed for all the images.

```
for(var i in icons){

  var rectx = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
  var recty = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);

  //console.log("i : "+i);

   if(icons[i]=="user"){

    var tip="user tooltip: "+i;
    console.log(tip);

    svg.append("image")
        .attr("id","user"+i)
        .attr('x',rectx)
        .attr('y',recty)
        .attr('width', 30)
        .attr('height', 24)
        .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.worryfreelabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/WFl_logo-2015-icon-only-white-background.png")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);  

            div .html("user tooltip: "+i)   
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })  

        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);
        });

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the scope of the variable. You can resolve this issue by implementing the functionality in a d3 way. Using [enter](https://d3js.org/#enter-exit) method.

```js
var imgHeight = 1025,
  imgWidth = 1538, // Image dimensions (don't change these)
  width = 500,
  height = 500, // Dimensions of cropped region
  translate0 = [-290, -180],
  scale0 = 1; // Initial offset & scale

svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + "px")
  .attr("height", height + "px");

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", width + "px")
  .attr("height", height + "px");

svg = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + translate0 + ")scale(" + scale0 + ")")
  .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
  .append("g");

svg.append("image")
  .attr("width", imgWidth + "px")
  .attr("height", imgHeight + "px")
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.myfreetextures.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/deep-green-grass-texture.jpg");

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);


function zoom() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

var max = 400,
  min = 200;

var icons = ["user", "user", "table"];

svg.selectAll("image.icon")
  .data(icons.filter(function(d) {    
    return d == "user";
  }))
  .enter()
  .append("image")
  .classed("icon", true)
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return "user" + i;
  })
  .attr('x', function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  })
  .attr('y', function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  })
  .attr('width', 30)
  .attr('height', 24)
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.worryfreelabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/WFl_logo-2015-icon-only-white-background.png")
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9);

    div.html("user tooltip: " + i)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  });


setInterval(function() {
  for (var i in icons) {

    if (icons[i] == "user") {
      d3.select("#user" + i).transition()
        .delay(1000)
        .attr('x', function(d) {
          return Math.random() * 720 - 29;
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) {
          return Math.random() * 200 - 30;
        })
        .duration(6000)
    }

  }
}, 500);
```

```css
.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. One more doubt if i need another image , if icon[i] == "table" and append another tooltip for it, how to do it? please explain.